# RoboCopy multithreading in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, robocopy, multi-threaded

The [RoboCopy reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx) specifically says 'The /MT parameter applies to Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7'. What is the behavior in Windows 10? I would hope multithreading is somehow the default, but I am not finding anything that actually says that.

Comment: There is nothing to indicate, even on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2, that RoboCopy by default would be multi-threaded.  So I seriously doubt a tool that hasn't seen a significant modification in years would magically have that defaulted (would also be extremely difficult to default since it depends on the number of cores/threads the system specifically supports).  So I can say without a shadow of a doubt, on Windows 10 RoboCopy is NOT multi-threaded, unless you use the MT parameter and specify the number of threads it should use.  *The parameter itself does have a default value though.*

Comment: So, Win8 behaves like Win7, and Microsoft is just not bothering to maintain their own documentation? I can work with that, but damn i wish MS would get their shit together and maintain some doco. ;)